# jQuery not filling div using .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jQuery script that I want to take the contents of the class "content" from another page and fill it into the div "code". I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#code1').load("http://git.kbiggs.org/mdwrapper/tree/mdwrapper .content");
  });
</script>
```

But all I get in the console is `[11:49:33.579] GET http://git.kbiggs.org/mdwrapper/tree/mdwrapper [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 46ms]`, and I see no changes in the page -- the div doesn't end up filling.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like a cross-domain request, is it? And I'm not sure you can use a class selector here, too.

Comment: You can get the url content using PHP.

Comment: Turns out you can indeed use a class selector in `load`, didn't know that. So it comes to 'Same Origin Policy', as domains should match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can simply load a page into a div without having a cross-domain problem. 
This is a security measure or else people everywhere would be loading content from other sites into their own.

You can achieve this by

1. using an iframe
2. using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP to extract the page and send it to your page.

Comment: Even if it's still part of my domain? The script is on www.kbiggs.org or kbiggs.org, which is the site root. I don't understand why the browser would block such traffic.

Comment: Anyway, how would I go about putting in an iframe that would just select a class from a page?

Comment: I didn't notice that you had a class there. Now for sure the .load method won't work. In my opinion, I would simply make an ajax call to a php script that would cURL the page and extract the wanted .content content. As for a jQuery method, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Well well well.. according to this site, it is possible.... http://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-just-a-section-of-a-page

Comment: I know it's possible to load a container of a page, problem is it seems like it won't work due to XSS-problems. I'll just make do with an iframe I guess.

Comment: because sub.example.com is considered a different domain than www.example.com. Read about the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).